# VBA - How do I group columns in a pivot table, collapse the group, and rename the label?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

How would I group columns in a pivot table, collapse the group, and rename the label given my pivot table "PivotTable1" look like the following:

[image: Pivot Table]

As you can my column labels are dates. Normally I would have to manually shift+click dates together and right click to group them into "Group#" Then rename the label into something more meaningful such as "Q1 2019" etc.

[image]

As you can see the 2 things I did above are grouping months Jan, Feb, Mar of 2018 together into one group, and renamed the label "Q1 2019".

Now this process becomes very time consuming and repetitive when the file goes off to 2030+ so I was wondering if there's any way to achieve this via VBA?

Again the goals of the macro would be:

1. Group column labels using some criteria - in my case grouping dates
   together into quarters.
2. Renaming the newly grouped column labels
3. Collapsing the newly created groups.

I can rename with something like the following.
`Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("date").PivotItems("rdates").Caption = "Q1 2019"`

Also I can manipulate pivotfields' attributes
    `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("date").Orientation = 
    xlHidden
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("date")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With`

but not sure how you would be able to group by criteria? I.E all jan-mar = Q1 + year